# Query to concatenate rows based on data from multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to print out xml results with a query in SQL Server 2014.

The query is supposed return data from a date range, and return a concatenated list of player names and player times.

The concatenation would ONLY occur if the `playEnd` was within 30 minutes of the next players `playStart`.

So if I have data like this:

```
Name        PlayDate         PlayStart      PlayEnd
----------------------------------------------------
player1 |   10/8/2018    |   08:00:00   |   09:00:00
player2 |   10/8/2018    |   09:10:00   |   10:10:00
player3 |   10/9/2018    |   10:40:00   |   11:30:00
player4 |   10/11/2018   |   08:30:00   |   08:37:00
player5 |   10/11/2018   |   08:40:00   |   08:50:00  
player6 |   10/12/2018   |   09:00:00   |   09:45:00
player7 |   10/12/2018   |   09:50:00   |   10:10:00
player8 |   10/12/2018   |   10:30:00   |   12:20:00
```

- player1 and player2 play times would be concatenated together like: player1, 
  player2 = 8:00:00 - 10:10:00 for 10/8/2018
- player3 would just be: player3 = 10:40:00 - 11:30:00 for 10/9/2018
- player4 and player5 play times would be concatenated like: player4, player5 = 08:30:00 - 08:50:00 for 10/11/2018
- player6 and player7 and player8 play times would be concatenated like: player6, player7, player8 = 09:00:00 - 12:20:00 for 10/12/2018

I've tried modifying the query below in many ways, but I just don't know how to compare one row of data with the next and then combine the two (or more) if needed.

```
select Name, PlayDate, PlayStart, PlayEnd
where playDate between '10/8/2018' and '10/12/2018'
for xml auto
```

Is there a way of doing this with SQL Server 2014?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming games are not played around midnight, you can do this using `lag()` and cumulative sums:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_playEnd is null or prev_playEnd < dateadd(-30, minute, playEnd)
                then 1 else 0
           end) over (partition by playdate order by playStart
                     ) as grouping
from (select t.*,
             lag(playEnd) over (partition by playdate order by playStart) as prev_playEnd
      from t
     ) t;
```

The column grouping has the information you want.

Comment: Thanks, the query works, but it just lists the players and a grouping number.  Would I group by grouping to get the concatenation?  Thanks!

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell . . . This provides the information you are asking for.  You can aggregate to get information about each grouping.